# Laravel - 2 css files with same group/permissions - one inaccessible

Tags: laravel, nginx, file-permissions, laravel-5

Not sure what happened. Maybe a recent update?
I push my code changes to my public environment from my repo with dploy.io and one of the post commands that I run are `php artisan update`. Not sure if a recent Laravel update changed anything.

```
kryptonit3@gandc:~/gandc$ php artisan --version
Laravel Framework version 5.0.14
```

Here is a css file that works (not 404)
https://gandc.co/css/bootstrap.min.css

Here is another that is also (according to Laravel) publically accessible and has same permissions/group
https://gandc.co/plugins/noUISlider/jquery.nouislider.min.css

But the second returns 404 even though it exists.

here is the one that works

```
kryptonit3@gandc:~/gandc/public/css$ ls -la
total 408
drwxrwxr-x 6 kryptonit3 www-data   4096 Mar 12 20:25 .
drwxrwxr-x 6 kryptonit3 www-data   4096 Mar 13 22:49 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 kryptonit3 www-data 130943 Mar  6 23:51 app.css
drwxrwxr-x 2 kryptonit3 www-data   4096 Mar  6 23:47 barcode
-rw-rw-r-- 1 kryptonit3 www-data 113498 Mar  6 23:51 bootstrap.min.css
-rw-rw-r-- 1 kryptonit3 www-data   1411 Mar  6 23:51 custom.css
drwxrwxr-x 2 kryptonit3 www-data   4096 Mar 12 20:25 dropzone
-rw-rw-r-- 1 kryptonit3 www-data  23739 Mar  6 23:51 font-awesome.min.css
drwxrwxr-x 2 kryptonit3 www-data   4096 Mar 12 20:25 html5imageupload
-rw-rw-r-- 1 kryptonit3 www-data 117877 Mar  6 23:51 nifty.min.css
drwxrwxr-x 2 kryptonit3 www-data   4096 Mar  9 16:45 noUISlider
```

and the one that does not

```
kryptonit3@gandc:~/gandc/public/plugins/noUiSlider$ ls -la
total 104
drwxrwxr-x  2 kryptonit3 www-data  4096 Mar 13 22:50 .
drwxrwxr-x 31 kryptonit3 www-data  4096 Mar 13 22:49 ..
-rw-rw-r--  1 kryptonit3 www-data 57355 Mar 13 22:50 jquery.nouislider.all.js
-rw-rw-r--  1 kryptonit3 www-data 18033 Mar 13 22:50 jquery.nouislider.all.min.js
-rw-rw-r--  1 kryptonit3 www-data  3078 Mar 13 22:50 jquery.nouislider.css
-rw-rw-r--  1 kryptonit3 www-data  1978 Mar 13 22:50 jquery.nouislider.min.css
-rw-rw-r--  1 kryptonit3 www-data  1317 Mar 13 22:50 jquery.nouislider.pips.css
-rw-rw-r--  1 kryptonit3 www-data  1045 Mar 13 22:50 jquery.nouislider.pips.min.css
```

the kryptonit3 user is a member of www-data, and the two files are chmod `644`

What gives? :\

when I move that same file to the `css` directory it works.

https://gandc.co/css/noUISlider/jquery.nouislider.min.css

```
kryptonit3@gandc:~/gandc/public/css/noUISlider$ ls -la
total 12
drwxrwxr-x 2 kryptonit3 www-data 4096 Mar  9 16:45 .
drwxrwxr-x 6 kryptonit3 www-data 4096 Mar 12 20:25 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 kryptonit3 www-data 1978 Mar 15 14:02 jquery.nouislider.min.css
```

This one file (jquery.nouislider.min.css) is just one example. None of the files outside of the `css` or `js` folders are accessible. I was under the impression everything in the `public` folder was accessible.

P.S. - not an issue in dev environment.

---

output of `ls -la ~/gandc/public/`

```
kryptonit3@gandc:~$ ls -la ~/gandc/public/
total 36
drwxrwxr-x  6 kryptonit3 www-data 4096 Mar 13 22:49 .
drwxrwxr-x 12 kryptonit3 www-data 4096 Mar  7 20:48 ..
drwxrwxr-x  6 kryptonit3 www-data 4096 Mar 12 20:25 css
-rw-rw-r--  1 kryptonit3 www-data    0 Mar  6 23:51 favicon.ico
-rw-rw-r--  1 kryptonit3 www-data  356 Mar 15 15:17 .htaccess
drwxrwxr-x  3 kryptonit3 www-data 4096 Mar 13 22:49 images
-rw-rw-r--  1 kryptonit3 www-data 1777 Mar  6 23:51 index.php
drwxrwxr-x  8 kryptonit3 www-data 4096 Mar 13 22:49 js
drwxrwxr-x 31 kryptonit3 www-data 4096 Mar 13 22:49 plugins
-rw-rw-r--  1 kryptonit3 www-data   24 Mar  6 23:51 robots.txt
```

output of .htaccess

```
kryptonit3@gandc:~/gandc/public$ cat .htaccess
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Please post the output of `ls -la ~/gandc/public/`.

Comment: You just need to use `/` before, `css/style.css` will not be work. It have to `/css/style.css` .

Comment: @SetKyarWaLar - this is not the issue, I use full domain URLs. The issue is the resource loading to begin with (hence the blank page when clicking the link to the resource)

Comment: Permissions look good, so the issue is most likely with the webserver. Laravel comes with a preconfigured `.htaccess` file included (which you posted), but that is only for Apache, not nginx. Have a look at [this article](http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/26/creating-a-nginx-virtualhost) to see how to configure Laravel with nginx, and if that doesn't help you figure out the issue, post your nginx configuration here.

Answer (score 0):

You site static files is served by nginx. You have to make sure there is a proper `location` section which serves `/plugins/noUISlider/jquery.nouislider.min.css` request, now it's handled incorrectly.

It's heavily depends on your other locations settings, but in general may look like this:

```
    location ~*  \plugins {
            root /home/gandc/gandc/public;
            // try other one if this will still throw 404
            // root /home/gandc/gandc/public/plugins;

            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;

            // cache related settings, it's good to have them when serving
            // static content such as css files or images
            expires 30d;
            add_header Cache-Control public,max-age=259200;
    }
```